# What are the fastest electron orbitals

Tags: atomic-physics

I read that the mercury has a low melting point because its outer shell electrons are pulled in close by its nucleus (large nucleus, sparse outer shell) and because its outer shell electrons have significant relativistic mass. I think I remember them being roughly 1.28x the rest mass of an electron. I calculated that as meaning they must travel at roughly 60% of the speed of light. But are there faster electrons? (in orbitals, not just free electrons)

Answer (score 2):

This is the domain of [relativistic quantum chemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_chemistry). This isn't something that has an easy upper bound, but you can imagine the 1-s orbital of ununoctium, if you'd like. On the extreme end you can imagine short-lived atoms in the vicinity of a [magnetar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar)

Comment: My guess is that the OP could use a little more explanation.  Why would the 1-s orbital of ununoctium be faster than 2-p of oxegen?  Why magnetars?

Comment: The extreme magnetic fields make electrons in atoms behave ultra-relativistically.

Regarding the first question, this is just a semi-classical guess (a la Bohr) but a 1-s orbital has greater speed than a 2-p orbital. Remember the Virial theorem $\langle T\rangle = -\frac{1}{2} \langle V \rangle$, or Kepler's laws if you like.